# Background image using Tkinter - Python 2.7

Tags: python, image, python-2.7, button, tkinter

I am trying to display a button over an image.The button appears to be in front of the image.
How can I set the image to the background of the app?
The button also needs to change his location, so the image should be permenant.

My code:

```
from Tkinter import *

class App:
def __init__(self,master):
    frame = Frame(master)
    master.geometry("400x200")
    frame.pack()

    self.hello_b = Button(master,text="ME",command=sys.exit, height=1, width=3,fg= "blue",bg = "green")
    self.hello_b.pack()


    photo = PhotoImage(file="unnamed.gif")
    w = Label (master, image=photo)
    w.place(x=0, y=0, relwidth=1, relheight=1)
    w.photo = photo
    w.pack()


root = Tk()
app = App(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Several things wrong.  There is much code extraneous to your problem, which means you wrote too much before testing.  Write and post an mcve https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.  You created and packed an unused frame.  You placed a Label with the photo on top of your packed Button. You then packed the photo a second time.

Comment: I edited and cleared things up. I hope now it is clearer.

Comment: My experiments with a .png in 3.5 indicate that setting the w.photo attribute is needed, but this is extremely unusual and not in the tkinter doc I have.  How did you know to do this?

Comment: By the internet.. I'm pretty new to python and trying to assemble knowledge from what I can read. I had .gif file I wanted to show and I used it. Can you suggest a way of showing the .gif in the background, while the button is over it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer, which I suspected, is [here](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/place.htm): "[the code] packs a Label widget in a frame widget, and then places a Button in the upper right corner of the frame. The button will overlap the label."  I tested like so

```
from tkinter import *

class App:
    def __init__(self,master):
        master.geometry("400x200")

        photo = PhotoImage(file="C:/programs/Python34/temimage.png")
        self.w = w = Label (master, image=photo)
        w.photo = photo
        w.pack()

        self.hello_b = Button(master,text="ME",command=sys.exit, height=1,
                              width=3,fg= "white",bg = "green")
        self.hello_b.place(x=200, y=5)

root = Tk()
app = App(root)
root.mainloop()
```

The button is indeed on top of the image. The x,y positions seems to be the upper left corner of the button. Adding

```
def move():
    app.hello_b.place(x=100, y=100)
root.after(1000, move)
```

caused the button to jump after a second, as expected.

Comment: Thank you very much. I suspected this was the problem but eliminated that option earlier. One more thing if I may: the button suppose to close the program on hit, but it just crashs the program. How do I make sys.exit work properly(or any other method)?

Comment: root.destroy -- see the example in the Python Reference chapter on tkinter. There are probably other answers on SO. root.destroy stops root.mainloop. Python executes any code that follows in the file, and if there is none, exits normally.  Directly using sys.exit is unusual.